# Twisted time counter

Tags: python, time, twisted, counter

I'm trying to write time counter with Twisted so that when I request GET /timer then it returns current count. First request starts the counter. Unfortunately, always when I request /timer it makes an additional new counter beginning from 0. Does anybody know, how to tweak the following code so that it doesn't create new counter every GET /timer request)?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class TimeCounter(Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def test(self):
        self.value += 1
        print self.value # debug
        reactor.callLater(1, self.test)

    def render(self, request):
        self.test()
        return str(self.value)

resource = TimeCounter()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  I tested this out a few months ago and it worked fine.  It will create a session cookie on the client.

```
class MyResource(Resource):
  # ...
  def render(self, request):
    session = request.getSession()
    if not hasattr(session, 'count'):
      session.count = itertools.count()
    request.write(u"Count is %s" % (session.count.next(),))
```